# execute command containing quotes in bash script

Tags: shell, scripting

I am trying to execute a shell script in which I call ExifTool to edit creation date on some files but in ExifTool syntax values of tag must be surrounded by single quotes, I tried several methods to escape those quotes but the creation dates won't change Here's my script

```
#!/bin/bash
#the argument is a directory name
cd $1
#I go in the directory
STRING="'$1 13:00:00 +00:00:00'"
#I create a variable to handle the quote issue
ls -1 |xargs -t -I _ xargs exiftool -filemodifydate=$STRING _
#I edit the creation date of the files contained in the directory with xargs and exiftool
ls -1|xargs -t -I _ mv _ ~/desktop/pictures/
#I move the files in another directory
cd ..
rm -r $1
#I remove the previous directory
```

Comment: Post code, not images

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote your variables when you **use** them, not when you **define** them:

```
cd "$1"
STRING="$1 13:00:00 +00:00:00"
# .....^   no single quotes  ^
ls -1 | xargs -t -I _ xargs exiftool -filemodifydate="$STRING" _
# ...................................................^.......^
# also, why 2 xargs ? ^^^^^
ls -1 | xargs -t -I _ mv _ ~/desktop/pictures/
cd ..
rm -r "$1"
```

But also, don't parse the output of `ls`, and using ALL_CAPS_VARNAMES is often a bad idea:

```
cd "$1"
datestring="$1 13:00:00 +00:00:00"
for file in *; do
    exiftool -filemodifydate="$datestring" _"$file"
    mv "$file" ~/desktop/pictures/
done
cd ..
rm -r "$1"
```